# Does Hive Optimizer consider view definition while optimizing queries on views?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, query-optimization

I have this schema (given through DDL for tables and views):

```
hive> create table t_realtime(cust_id int, name string, status string, active_flag int);

hive> create table t_hdfs(cust_id int, name string, status string, active_flag int);

hive> create view t_inactive as select * from t_hdfs where active_flag=0;

hive> create view t_view as select * from t_realtime union all select * from t_inactive;
```

If I fire a query as follows:

```
hive> select * from t_view where active_flag = 1;
```

This query ideally should not visit `t_inactive` view or `t_hdfs` at all, since the view definition for `t_inactive` itself has `active_flag = 0` and query predicate has `active_flag = 1`. However, by default, it does not eliminate `t_inactive` part of this union view.

Is there anyway to achieve this for such hive query? Maybe some hive optimizer parameter or a hint?

Comment: Base on what have you decided that "by default, it does not eliminate t_inactive part of this union view."

Answer (score 1):

```
hive> explain extended select * from t_view where active_flag = 1;
OK
STAGE DEPENDENCIES:
  Stage-0 is a root stage

STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: -1
      Processor Tree:
        TableScan
          alias: t_realtime
          properties:
            insideView TRUE
          GatherStats: false
          Filter Operator
            isSamplingPred: false
            predicate: (active_flag = 1) (type: boolean)
            Select Operator
              expressions: cust_id (type: int), name (type: string), status (type: string), 1 (type: int)
              outputColumnNames: _col0, _col1, _col2, _col3
              ListSink
```

This is tested on yesterday's mainline (at d68630b6ed25884a76030a9073cd864032ab85c2). As you can see, it only scans `t_realtime` and pushes down the predicate `active_flag = 1`. Whether *your* particular installation will do this or not, it depends on what version you're using. This topic is subject to active development, not only on Hive but also on [Calcite](https://calcite.apache.org/) (used by Hive).

Comment: Thanks very much!!

Comment: Can you please mention the version of Hive you have tried with? Are you suggesting that its work in progress in latest Hive version branch?